# Add unit as single tick label

Tags: pgfplots, axis, ticks, units

I want to use the second to last tick label as the place for my unit, as shown below.
Is there a way to replace it?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}]
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I tried applying it to my data with the following x- and y-ranges, but the dimension seems to be to big?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    scaled x ticks = false,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=20000,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=3000,
    ytick={0,500,...,3000},
    xticklabel={\ifdim\tick pt=18000pt Hz \else \axisdefaultticklabel\fi},
    yticklabel={\ifdim\tick pt=2500pt - \else \axisdefaultticklabel\fi},
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {(19000,2000)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

EDIT2: Using either of the commands screws up the semilogy ticks.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{semilogyaxis}[
     xmin=0,
     xmax=2000,
     log ticks with fixed point,
     ymin=0.0001,
     ymax=0.1,
     xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)} \ifnum \pgfmathresult=1500 test \else \axisdefaultticklabel\fi},
     % yticklabel={\ifdim\tick pt=0.01pt \unit{\newton} \else \axisdefaultticklabel\fi},
     yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)} \ifnum \pgfmathresult=0.01 test \else \axisdefaultticklabel\fi},
   ]
   \end{semilogyaxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

\end{document}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
xmin=0, xmax=4,
ymin=-0.45, ymax=0.05,
xtick distance=0.5, ytick distance=0.05,
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1},
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=2},
xticklabel={\ifdim\tick pt=3.5pt mm \else \axisdefaultticklabel\fi},
yticklabel={\ifdim\tick pt=0.0pt mm \else \axisdefaultticklabel\fi},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Empty graph with custom ticks]

**Edit:** A version that works with higher numbers

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=\textwidth, height=0.5\textwidth,
scaled x ticks=false,
xmin=0, xmax=20000,
ymin=0, ymax=3000,
xtick distance=2000, ytick distance=500,
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)} \ifnum \pgfmathresult=18000 Hz \else \axisdefaultticklabel\fi},
yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(\tick)} \ifnum \pgfmathresult=2500 Hz \else \axisdefaultticklabel\fi},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Empty graph with custom ticks]

Comment: This is great! Can you explain a bit how it works?

Comment: `\ifdim ... \else ... \fi` is the LaTeX test recommended in the PGFPlots manual. -it tests for a specific value of the `\tick`. -so it is only the second to last because of the manual selected values `3.5` and `0.0`.

Comment: Far better than mine rude solution , so +1. I went back to package documentation and read it again .

Comment: @Zarko: I am not sure - it is a different way. I also have no way to say "Replace second to last". -so both solutions are manual in a sense.

Comment: I got error the error "Dimension too large. \\pgfplots@xticklabel ->\\ifdim \\tick pt=18000pt" when using a different range

Comment: @fuj36840: There is no problem in asking additional questions in the comments, but you can not always expect an answer. That is why you should not un-accept an answer. -do *not* move the goal post.  Only un-accept to accept an other answer that suits your need better. Remember you can also always ask a new question with a link to the old one.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Here's another one: using either of the commands screws up the semilogy ticks. I put a new MWE in the question.

Answer (score 2):

As skeleton, drawing of function is left to you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid,
    xlabel = {$x$}, 
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xmin=0, xmax=4,
    xtick = {0,0.5,...,4},
    xticklabels = {0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,mm,4},
    ymin=-0.45, ymax=0,
    ytick = {-0.45,-0.40,..., 0.0},
    yticklabels = {-0.45,-0.40,-0.35,-0.25,-0.20,-0.15,-0.10,-0.05, mm, 0.0},
            ]
%\addplot [domain=0:4] {1};
\end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]